# Angular 4 CKeditor 5 building from source and building to ES5 webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, ckeditor5

I am trying to build CKEditor 5 Balloon Editor from source instead of using an existing build.

I am following the directions per https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#scenario-2-building-from-source

The error I am getting is `Module build failed: TypeError: this.options.translateSource is not a function`. It spits this error out for every plugin I have manually added.

When I comment out my current entry object and place this:

```
entry: [
    require.resolve( 'regenerator-runtime/runtime.js' ),

    // your entries...
]
```

it compiles and gets rid of the error, but I need to place it in my entry object that looks like this:

```
"entry": {
  "main": [
      "./src/main.ts",
      "./src/app/" + process.env.APP_NAME + "/main.ts"
    ],
    "polyfills": [
      "./src/polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "styles": ["./src/styles.scss"]
  },
```

When I try to add the regenerate line as its own property under "entry", like

```
"entry": {
      "main": [
          "./src/main.ts",
          "./src/app/" + process.env.APP_NAME + "/main.ts"
        ],
      "regenerate": "require.resolve( 'regenerator-runtime/runtime.js' )",
        "polyfills": [
          "./src/polyfills.ts"
        ],
        "styles": ["./src/styles.scss"]
      },
```

it doesn't solve it. I've tried to put it in an array like the others, I've tried to delete the require.resolve part, I've tried to put it as a string under the "main" property, and nothing works. I get the same error.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Is it just a typo that you wrapped `require.resolve()` in `""` in the last code sample?

Comment: @Reinmar yes, even without the `""` it still gives the same error. Here is one example of the error, this one the heading plugin:

`ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading.js
Module build failed: TypeError: this.options.translateSource is not a function
    at Object.translateSourceLoader (/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin/lib/translatesourceloader.js:16:22)`

Comment: Which webpack version do you use? webpack 4 causes issues. See https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev/issues/371.

Comment: @Reinmar using `webpack 3.x.x`

Comment: Odd... you get exactly the same error, in the same line, as the author of that ticket. Could you perhaps open a new ticket there? But to check it we'd need a working project in which we could reproduce this issue.